# LEFT JOIN SUM with WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, left-join

The following query always outputs SUM for all rows instead of per `userid`. Not sure where else to look. Please help.

```
SELECT * FROM assignments
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT SUM(timeworked) AS totaltimeworked
            FROM time_entries
        ) assignments ON (userid = assignments.userid AND ticketid = ?) 
        WHERE       ticketid = ?
        ORDER BY    assigned,scheduled
```

Comment: What you are trying to achieve its better if you include table definition with sample desired data set also sum is an aggregate function you might need a group by statement aggregate functions without group by will result as a single row assuming all rows as one group

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid: I'm trying to get `SUM` of `timeworked` for each `userid` in `time_entries` associated with `userid` in `assigments`.

Comment: Read up on aggregate functions

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the SELECT *, you would have to add a group by clause in the subquery. Something like this

```
SELECT * FROM assignments
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT SUM(timeworked) AS totaltimeworked
        FROM time_entries
        GROUP BY userid
    ) time_entriesSummed ON time_entriesSummed.userid = assignments.userid
    WHERE       ticketid = ?
    ORDER BY    assigned,scheduled
```

But a better way would be to change the SELECT * to instead select the fields you want a add a group by clause directly. Something like this

```
 SELECT
    assignments.id,
    assignments.assigned,
    assignments.scheduled,
    SUM(time_entries.timeworked) AS totalTimeworked
 FROM assignments
 LEFT JOIN time_entries 
 ON time_entries.userid = assignments.userid
 GROUP BY assignments.id, assignments.assigned, assignments.scheduled
```

**Edit 1**
Included table names in query 2 as mentioned in chameera's comment below

Comment: `timeworked` doesn't exist in `assignments` table, it only exists in `time_entries`

Comment: @AlexG  use `timeworked` column with table name as `SUM(time_entries.timeworked)`

Comment: @AlexG Can you include your table structure and desired output sample?